# Cannot deserialize scandinavian characthers from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, magento, soap

I am using Magento 1.7 with their SOAP api to retreive orders to my .Net environement.
Everything is OK except characther encoding. Chars such as Å, Ä and Ö is translated to ??.

The response from Fiddler shows that server (Litespeed) actually sends the corrects chars in UTF-8. The MySql database is also encoded in UTF-8.

Fiddlers raw:

```
<city xsi:type="xsd:string">Å Ä Ö</city>
```

Any ideas on how to force my c# client to not render this as ?? ?? ??.. ?

Comment: I don't think that there are a lot of people who knows Magento. If you can - will be good to post the code which loads these response.

Comment: This is not Magento's fault ( whatever Magento is) but the client code doesn't interpret the response correctly.

Comment: I never said it's Magentos fault, I'm asking how I can force my client to interpret the response correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify CultureInfo : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I went completely nuts and solved it in the probably worst way but it did help me accomplish my task since setting cultureinfo or setting requestencoding on the webclient did not help: a custom SoapExtension:

```
Public Class MySoapExtension
Inherits SoapExtension
Private oldStream As Stream
Private newStream As Stream

Public Overrides Function ChainStream(stream As Stream) As Stream
    oldStream = stream
    newStream = New MemoryStream()
    Return newStream
End Function

Public Overloads Overrides Function GetInitializer(methodInfo As  _
    LogicalMethodInfo, _
  attribute As SoapExtensionAttribute) As Object

End Function

Public Overloads Overrides Function GetInitializer(WebServiceType As  _
  Type) As Object

End Function

Public Overrides Sub Initialize(initializer As Object)

End Sub
Public Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(message As SoapMessage)
    Select Case message.Stage
        Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize
        Case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize
            WriteOutput(message)
        Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize
            WriteInput(message)
        Case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("invalid stage")
    End Select
End Sub

' Write the SOAP message out to a file.
Public Sub WriteOutput(message As SoapMessage)
    newStream.Position = 0
    Copy(newStream, oldStream)
End Sub

' Write the SOAP message out to a file.
Public Sub WriteInput(message As SoapMessage)
    Copy(oldStream, newStream)
    newStream.Position = 0
End Sub

Sub Copy(fromStream As Stream, toStream As Stream)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(fromStream)
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(toStream)
    writer.WriteLine(ReplaceInvalidChars(reader.ReadToEnd()))
    writer.Flush()
End Sub

Private Function ReplaceInvalidChars(ByVal content As String) As String
    If content.Contains("salesOrderInfo") Then
        Return MagentoHackHelper.Encode(content)
    Else
        Return content
    End If
End Function

End Class

Public Class MagentoHackHelper

Public Shared Function Encode(content As String) As String
    content = content.Replace("Å", "##Aaring##")
    content = content.Replace("Ä", "##Auml##")
    content = content.Replace("Ö", "##Ouml##")

    content = content.Replace("å", "##aaring##")
    content = content.Replace("ä", "##auml##")
    content = content.Replace("ö", "##ouml##")

    Return content
End Function

Public Shared Function Decode(content As String) As String
    content = content.Replace("##Aaring##", "Å")
    content = content.Replace("##Auml##", "Ä")
    content = content.Replace("##Ouml##", "Ö")

    content = content.Replace("##aaring##", "Å")
    content = content.Replace("##auml##", "Ä")
    content = content.Replace("##ouml##", "Ö")

    Return content
End Function

End Class
```